# Deploying NodeRED Docker image to Heroku fails, but local build is error free

Tags: docker, heroku, node-red

We are trying to push a Docker image based on NodeRED to Heroku. Local build and test runs like a charm, but when we deploy it to Heroku, the Docker image build fails. Our docker file is quite simple:

```
FROM nodered/node-red
USER node-red

# Copy package.json to the WORKDIR so npm builds all
COPY package.json .
RUN mkdir -p node-red-static
COPY node-red-static/ node-red-static/
COPY defaults .
# NodeRED configuration
COPY .node-red/settings.js /usr/src/node-red/.node-red/settings.js
COPY .node-red/flows.json /data/flows.json
COPY package.json /usr/src/node-red/package.json
# Actual installation
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --no-update-notifier --no-fund --only=production
```

(I also tried without setting the user)

The `heroku.yml`:

```yaml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

The error on `git push heroku master`:

```sh
npm WARN saveError EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/node-red/package.json'
remote: npm WARN saveError EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/node-red/package.json'
remote: npm WARN Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/node-red/package.json'
remote: npm WARN  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/src/node-red/package.json']
remote: npm WARN   stack:
remote: npm WARN    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, open \'/usr/src/node-red/package.json\'',
remote: npm WARN   errno: -13,
remote: npm WARN   code: 'EACCES',
remote: npm WARN   syscall: 'open',
remote: npm WARN   path: '/usr/src/node-red/package.json' }
remote: npm WARN node-red No description
remote: npm WARN node-red No repository field.
remote: npm WARN node-red No README data
remote: npm WARN node-red No license field.
remote: 
remote: audited 627 packages in 2.146s
```

What do I miss?

**Update**

The package.json

```json
{
  "name": "insect-core",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.1.0",
    "npm": "7.9.0"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node-red --settings ./.node-red/settings-development.js --userDir ./.node-red",
    "start": "node-red --settings ./.node-red/settings.js --userDir /data",
    "debug": "node-red --inspector --settings ./.node-red/settings.js --userDir ./.node-red",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
  "author": "techdev@protenga.com",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-red": "^1.3.5",
    "node-red-configurable-ping": "^1.0.1",
    "node-red-contrib-auth": "^0.1.7",
    "node-red-contrib-cloudantplus": "^0.3.0",
    "node-red-contrib-dashboard-bar-chart-data": "^0.9.7",
    "node-red-contrib-dnsquery": "^1.0.6",
    "node-red-contrib-env": "^1.0.2",
    "node-red-contrib-fast-csv": "^0.4.0",
    "node-red-contrib-google": "^0.2.0",
    "node-red-contrib-google-sheets": "^0.1.0",
    "node-red-contrib-jwt": "^0.1.0",
    "node-red-contrib-loop-processing": "^0.5.1",
    "node-red-contrib-md5": "^1.0.4",
    "node-red-contrib-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "node-red-contrib-objectcleaner": "0.0.3",
    "node-red-contrib-redis": "^1.3.9",
    "node-red-contrib-simple-message-queue": "^0.2.7",
    "node-red-contrib-simple-sendmail": "^0.1.9",
    "node-red-contrib-socketio": "^1.0.7",
    "node-red-contrib-uuid": "0.0.4",
    "node-red-node-rbe": "^0.5.0",
    "node-red-node-tail": "^0.3.1"
  }
}
```

Just to clarify:

What fails:

```sh
heroku stack:set container
git push heroku master
```

which tries to build the container on heroku

What worked:

```sh
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web --app insectos
heroku container:release web --app insectos
```

Comment: What is in the `package.json` you are copying to the `/usr/src/node-red` directory? You should not really be changing this file. All the customisation should probably in `/data`. Likewise the `settings.js` should also be put in `/data`

Comment: package.json contains the tailored list of nodes we use. Removed the ones we don’t use. Added the ones we use. This is a runtime deployment

Comment: Edit the question to show that file, but that is the wrong file to change, it should be the one in `/data`

Comment: OK, I see you've totally changed the default `scripts` section in the `/usr/src/node-red/package.json`. Given the amount of changes it's probably not worth using the official node-red image as a base any more as you are basically ignoring everything it sets up.

Comment: I'll change stuff back, not trying to reinvent the wheel. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, copying `settings.js` to `/usr/app/node-red/.node-red` will do nothing as it will be ignored. The `usrDir` for the Node-RED Docker container is `/data` so the `settings.js` needs to be copied to there.

Second, to install extra nodes add them to the `package.json` in `/data` not `/usr/src/node-red`. Then run `npm install ...` in the `/data` directory, this will install the nodes into `/data/node_modules`.

If you want to remove any of the core nodes then you need to included their filenames in the `nodesExcludes` key in the  `settings.js` as follows:

```
...
nodesExcludes: [ '90-exec.js', '10-file.js'],
...
```